# CMD: How to check if one or more parameters are given

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to check if one or two parameters are given by the user. Depending on that, different functions will apply.

How can i use anything like OR or AND in this case?

```
  @echo off
    :BEGIN
            echo START
    
            set /p var1=
            set /p var2=
    
            if %var1%=="" if %var2%=="" goto BEGIN
            if exist %var1% OR %var2% goto ONE
            if exist %var1% if exist %var2% goto TWO
    
    :ONE
            ECHO You give only one parameter
            <code here>
            goto EXIT
    
    :TWO
            ECHO You give two parameters
            <code here>
            goto EXIT
    
    
    :EXIT
    exit
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Batch simply doesn't have logical operators, but you nearly get a solution.

In batch, string compares are a bit different than in other languages.

The variable has to be enclosed in quotes, too.
`if "%var1%"==""`

Then your code looks like

```
@echo off
:BEGIN
echo START

set "var1="
set "var2="
set /p var1=
set /p var2=

if "%var1%"=="" if "%var2%"=="" goto BEGIN
if "%var1%" NEQ "" if "%var2%" NEQ "" goto TWO
goto :ONE

:ONE
ECHO You give only one parameter
<code here>
goto EXIT

:TWO
ECHO You give two parameters
<code here>
goto EXIT


:EXIT
exit
```

Instead of using a string compare you could also use the `IF DEFINED` syntax

```
if not defined var1 if not defined var2 goto begin
if defined var1 if defined var2 goto TWO
```

Btw. I added the `set "var1="` to undefine the variable before the `set /p`, because a `set /p` will not change (or empty) a variable, for an empty input.

Comment: Works perfectly, many thanks!

Comment: You might consider putting the check after each `set \p` statement: then you can offer options such as default, redo or exit via an internal function call.